# sqlDashboard MSSQL login with windows authorization

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

I have an MSSQL database that used Windows Authentication. How can I connect to my database with sqlDashboard? I have tried putting in the login name and password that I use to login to Windows but that does not work.

Comment: I don't know what is sqlDashboard but if your server use Windows Authentication only you should not use any login/password, you are already authenticated in Windows and this "sqlDashboard" should just pass your tokens to server

Comment: There are many products and open source libraries called `SQL Dashoboard` or any combination of the words. Which are you talking about?